# How can I block employers from messaging on "Careers"

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, spam

I have been messaged twice now by a company that is looking for somebody that's an "expert with five years experience" in something that I clearly don't do.

They haven't even spent 5 mins reading my CV. Rather than declining them repeatedly can I just block them somehow?

Comment: Wow, that's gotta be frustrating.  But don't you risk losing the legitimate messages?  What if one of those messages is the perfect job you've been looking for all your life? :P

Comment: Getting job roles, any kind, with any skill, anywhere spammed to me on mass is happening already I don't need stack exchange for that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry to hear that. You can block employers by selecting "not interested", indicating the reason, and checking the "block employer" check box. If you want you can also send an email to careers@stackoverflow.com to let us know what company was contacting you.